# Drawtype for objects in blender 2.8

Tags: draw-mode

How do you change the maximum object drawtype of an object in blender 2.8?
Eg, I want to make a cube so that it is seen in the viewport as a wireframe, but I don't want to be in wire frame as I have other objects I want to see as solid volumes.

Answer (score 5):

Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display As Wire

You might want to check "All Edges" too to draw coplanar edges (edges lying on the same plane)

[image]

With python

```
import bpy 
ob = bpy.context.object
ob.display_type = 'WIRE'
ob.show_all_edges = True
```